# Error shows "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword WHERE"

Tags: sql-server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    FO.Placement_date, FO.Delivery_date, FO.Order_Id, FO.Cid, 
    CPD.Name, FOD.Product, FOD.Type, FOD.Article_Quantity, 
    FOD.Quantity_In_Metre, FOD.Price_Per_Metre, FPD.Total, 
    Discount, FPD.OfferDiscount, FPD.ExtraCharges 
FROM 
    F_Orders_Details FOD 
INNER JOIN 
    F_PaymentDetails FPD 
INNER JOIN 
    F_Orders FO ON FO.Order_Id = FOD.Order_Id   
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerIds CPD ON CPD.Cid = FO.Cid 
                    AND CPD.BranchId = FO.BranchId 
WHERE 
    FO.Placement_Date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'  
    AND FO.branchid = '1' 
ORDER BY 
    FO.Placement_Date
```

I did not find anything wrong.

Comment: You have no `JOIN` criteria for this `inner join F_PaymentDetails FPD `. If you formatted it properly, you would see that.

Comment: please give the link of exact problem

Comment: I did give you the exact line that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a ON clause on the first inner join which relates FOD and FDP. I reformatted the code slightly so you can spot it more easily:

```
SELECT FO.Placement_date,
       FO.Delivery_date,
       FO.Order_Id,
       FO.Cid,
       CPD.Name,
       FOD.Product,
       FOD.Type,
       FOD.Article_Quantity,
       FOD.Quantity_In_Metre,
       FOD.Price_Per_Metre,
       FPD.Total,
       FPD.Discount,
       FPD.OfferDiscount,
       FPD.ExtraCharges
FROM   F_Orders_Details FOD
       INNER JOIN F_PaymentDetails FPD /*On what?*/
       INNER JOIN F_Orders FO
         ON FO.Order_Id = FOD.Order_Id
       INNER JOIN CustomerIds CPD
         ON CPD.Cid = FO.Cid
            AND CPD.BranchId = FO.BranchId
WHERE  FO.Placement_Date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
       AND FO.branchid = '1'
ORDER  BY FO.Placement_Date
```